# multiple geocoder requests google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I've been using Google Maps API v3 and geocoder to display a map and it's working well so far. When I tried to display another map on the same page only the first map loads. The second map simply shows a gray area. No map is loaded. I have to do multiple geocoder requests, but how do I go about it. Here is my code so far:

```
    var geocoder;
var map;
var map2;
var marker;
var infobox;

function initialize() {
            //Geocoder
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = 'Times Square, New York'; 
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            //Marker
            var companyLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/pin.png',
                new google.maps.Size(20,20),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(10,10)
                );
            //Marker shadow 
            var companyShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/pin_shadow.png',
                new google.maps.Size(25,33),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 25)
                );
            //Display the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: companyLogo,
                shadow: companyShadow,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title:"Some title"
            });
            //Infobox
            infobox = new InfoBox({
                content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 320,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-142, -150),
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: {
                    opacity: 1,
                    width: "300px"
                    },
                closeBoxMargin: "0px",
                closeBoxURL: "images/close_tooltip.png",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                });
                        //Open infobox
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                infobox.open(map, this);
                map.panTo(geocoder);
                });

            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });

                    //Map options
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
    //Call Maps 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), myOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: "It's not working"... *What* is not working? The geocoder? The second map? What do you mean by "not working"? What errors are logged in the error console? (etc, etc)

Comment: sorry i should have specified. the first map is working fine. the second map simply won't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myOptions` object you use to set up the second map does not contain a `center` property, so the second map cannot be centred.

When the geocoder is called, you set the centre of the first map:

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

but you do not set the second map.

Without setting the map's centre, it will remain grey and empty.

Comment: Thanks that made the map appear, but of course only with one and the same location in both maps. I have two identical maps now. Could you point me towards a solution for how to get two or more different locations?

Comment: You *could* just repeat the code you already have for `map`, but use `map2` so that the results get applied to the right map. However, you should not be geocoding known locations every time the page is opened anyway. Just find the coordinates of the places you want to show, and set each map's centre with a `setCenter()`. Far less code to go wrong and fewer calls on Google's resources (and it's faster for your users too).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm looking to work with Wordpress though, so the locations will be unknown and added by the user for each post. Anyway I figured something out.